# Como evitar que se inserten 2 valores iguales en un form input

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo mi codigo en HTML donde recibo varios input atravez de un foreach de una tabla en una BD, normalmente esto arroja 3 o 4 campos para ingresar numeros dependiendo de los datos, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
foreach($data["usuarios"] as $dato){
        $pco_nombre = $dato["pco_nombre"];
        ?> <p class="card-text"><strong><?= echo $pco_nombre; ?></strong></p>
        <label>Votacion:</label>
        <input type="number" name="votacion[]" id="votacion"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit3" name="boton1" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Guardar" type="button">Asignar Votacion</button>
        </div>    
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como podrìa hacer que de los valores que se ingresen en el campo: " `<input type="number" name="votacion[]" id="votacion"></input>`, se validen antes de redireccionar al action del form, de tal forma que si el valor que se ingresó en el campo 1 es igual al campo 2,3 o 4 se mande un tipo de alerta? Muchas gracias de antemano! Agradezco cualquier aporte.

Comment: Tienes que tomar el control del formulario en el evento submit (addeventlistener) colocas epreventdefault() y puedes hacer las validaciones que quieras

Comment: Hola @HernánGarcia Gracias por recomendarmelo, pero mi pregunta surge ¿ como identifico las variables a la hora de validarlas dentro de un foreach? Teniendo en cuenta que el nombre es el mismo en todos `name="votacion[]"`

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es eliminar el id, los id no se deben de repetir, cambialos por clase, y con javascript solo recorres los controles que tengan la clase que le asignes dentro de las iteraciones validas si existe otro input con el value repetido

Comment: @HeynerMartinez ¿Podrías mostrarme con un ejemplo lo que me acabas de decir? Soy realmente nuevo en esto y quisiera documentarme acerca de ello, Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de lo que necesitas

Recorrer los inputs con la clase y verificar el value para ver si se repite

```js
function validator()
{
const controls=document.querySelectorAll('.votacion');
let ids=[];
controls.forEach(function(control)
    {
      if(ids.includes(control.value))
      {
        alert('Se encontraron valores duplicados');
        return;
      }
      ids.push(control.value);
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="votacion[]" class="votacion"></input>
<input type="number" name="votacion[]" class="votacion"></input>
<input type="number" name="votacion[]" class="votacion"></input>
<input type="number" name="votacion[]" class="votacion"></input>
<input type="number" name="votacion[]" class="votacion"></input>
<input type="number" name="votacion[]" class="votacion"></input>
<button onclick=validator();>Validar</button>
```

Comment: Hola Heyner, muchas gracias por compartir ese conocimiento, es de apreciar bastante; ¿Existe de alguna forma que dentro de ese JavaScript si hay valores duplicados no redirija al action dentro del form?

Comment: @Decox si claro si se puede, pero se haría desde el evento submit del formulario y usando el prevent default, y a la funciión que te comente modificarla para que retorne un boolean, si retorna true (hay reptidos) no rediriges, cheka ese enlace como usar el prevent default https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/javascript/prevent-form-submit-javascript/